# "std_lib_facilities.h" (from Programming: Principles and Practices by Bjarne Stroustrup) does not work

Tags: c++

I have Microsoft Visual 2010. This won't header file doesn't work.
The code for the file is [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h).

The two errors are:

```
#ifndef H112
```

"Error: the #endif file for this directive is missing"

```
typedef long Unicode;
```

"Error: PCH warning: header cannot be in macro or #if block. An intellisense PCH file was not generated"

The output for the build shows:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld!, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
>
> 1>  HelloWorld!.cpp
>
> 1>c:\users\hp\desktop\c++ programming\helloworld!\helloworld!\std_lib_facilities.h(55): fatal error C1070: mismatched #if/#endif pair in file 'c:\users\hp\desktop\c++ programming\helloworld!\helloworld!\std_lib_facilities.h'
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

What should I do? I'm learning from Programming: Principles and Practices using C++ Bjarne Stroustrup. I have stored this file with in the folder of my source code.

EDIT : I copy-pasted the whole code again. The 1st error disappeared. But the 2nd error is still there. :(

Comment: The intellisense "error" is not an error.  The first one is odd, though.

Comment: Did you forget to copy the last line with the `#endif`?

Comment: I copy-pasted the whole code again. The 1st error disappeared. But the 2nd error is still there. :(

Comment: I deleted the header file and build the solution again. Idk what happened. Problem solved.

Answer (score -3):

At the end of the program change "#endif //H112" to "#endif H112"

Comment: Incorrect.  Although MSVC will allow this it does not conform to the standard, is totally necessary and definitely not the problem. There is nothing wrong with Bjarne's code and I would have been very surprised if there had been.